# Reshape binomial data to long bernoulli format

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, rpart

I am coming back to R after a year and want to use rpart for a classification tree.

My data looks like:

```
Category, Shape, Color, Yes, No
A, Square, Blue, 3, 2
B, Triangle, Blue, 2, 4
etc.
```

Any recommendations to reshape into the below so I can use rpart? (I believe rpart needs the data as such)

```
ID, Shape, Color, Result
A, Square, Blue, Yes
A, Square, Blue, Yes
A, Square, Blue, Yes
A, Square, Blue, No
A, Square, Blue, No
B, Triangle, Green, Yes
etc...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `melt` from `reshape2` , then follow by `rep`

```
s=melt(df,id.var=c('Category','Shape','Color'))
s[ rep( 1:nrow(s) , s$value ),]
              Category     Shape Color variable value
1                    A    Square  Blue      Yes     3
1.1                  A    Square  Blue      Yes     3
1.2                  A    Square  Blue      Yes     3
2                    B  Triangle  Blue      Yes     2
2.1                  B  Triangle  Blue      Yes     2
3                    A    Square  Blue       No     2
3.1                  A    Square  Blue       No     2
4                    B  Triangle  Blue       No     4
4.1                  B  Triangle  Blue       No     4
4.2                  B  Triangle  Blue       No     4
4.3                  B  Triangle  Blue       No     4
```

Answer (score 1):

`melt` the data into a long format, then repeat the variable the number of times they appear in the value column.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dat),1:3)[,rep(variable,value),by=.(Category,Shape,Color)]
            Category     Shape Color  V1
 1:                A    Square  Blue Yes
 2:                A    Square  Blue Yes
 3:                A    Square  Blue Yes
 4:                A    Square  Blue  No
 5:                A    Square  Blue  No
 6:                B  Triangle  Blue Yes
 7:                B  Triangle  Blue Yes
 8:                B  Triangle  Blue  No
 9:                B  Triangle  Blue  No
10:                B  Triangle  Blue  No
11:                B  Triangle  Blue  No
```

using:

library(tidyverse)

```
dat%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(var=list(rep(c("Yes","No"),c(Yes,No))))%>%
  select(-Yes,-No)%>%
  unnest()
 Category   Shape    Color var  
  <fct>    <fct>    <fct> <chr>
 1 A        Square   Blue  Yes  
 2 A        Square   Blue  Yes  
 3 A        Square   Blue  Yes  
 4 A        Square   Blue  No   
 5 A        Square   Blue  No   
 6 B        Triangle Blue  Yes  
 7 B        Triangle Blue  Yes  
 8 B        Triangle Blue  No   
 9 B        Triangle Blue  No   
10 B        Triangle Blue  No   
11 B        Triangle Blue  No
```